# Errors when using GLSurfaceView.onPause()

Tags: android, andengine, glsurfaceview

I'm developing an Android game with AndEngine, and i'm getting the following error within the logCat:

```
01-13 20:44:46.726: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onPause @(Thread: 'main')
01-13 20:44:46.726: I/GLThread(16843): onPause tid=17
01-13 20:44:46.726: I/Main thread(16843): onPause waiting for mPaused.
01-13 20:44:46.734: I/GLThread(16843): mPaused is now true tid=17
01-13 20:44:46.734: I/GLThread(16843): releasing EGL surface because paused tid=17
01-13 20:44:46.734: W/EglHelper(16843): destroySurface()  tid=17
01-13 20:44:46.734: D/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 16858
01-13 20:44:46.734: D/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x219018, android          window 0x2187f8, Thread: 16858
01-13 20:44:46.734: W/EglHelper(16843): finish() tid=17
01-13 20:44:46.734: D/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglDestroyContext() context: 0x266ec8, VC  context: 1, Thread 16858
01-13 20:44:46.734: E/EGL_SERVER(16843): pid mem_get_free_space before =  5ffb80
01-13 20:44:46.734: E/EGL_SERVER(16843): pid mem_get_free_space =  5ffb80
01-13 20:44:46.750: I/GLThread(16843): releasing EGL context because paused tid=17
01-13 20:44:46.750: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onPauseGame @(Thread: 'main')
01-13 20:44:46.859: I/GLThread(16843): noticed surfaceView surface lost tid=17
01-13 20:44:48.843: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onResume @(Thread: 'main')
01-13 20:44:48.843: I/GLThread(16843): onResume tid=17
01-13 20:44:48.843: I/Main thread(16843): onResume waiting for !mPaused.
01-13 20:44:48.843: I/GLThread(16843): mPaused is now false tid=17
01-13 20:44:48.851: I/GLThread(16843): noticed surfaceView surface acquired tid=17
01-13 20:44:48.851: W/EglHelper(16843): start() tid=17
01-13 20:44:48.859: D/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglCreateContext() context: 0x266ec8, VC context    1, Thread 16858
01-13 20:44:48.859: W/EglHelper(16843): createContext  com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLContextImpl@40521008 tid=17
01-13 20:44:48.859: W/GLThread(16843): egl createSurface
01-13 20:44:48.859: W/EglHelper(16843): createSurface()  tid=17
01-13 20:44:48.859: D/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x219018, VC surface: 1, Thread: 16858
01-13 20:44:48.859: D/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglMakeCurrent(0x266ec8, 0x219018, 0x219018) Thread: 16858
01-13 20:44:48.859: I/Main thread(16843): onWindowResize waiting for render complete from tid=17
01-13 20:44:48.867: W/GLThread(16843): onSurfaceCreated
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): VERSION: OpenGL ES 2.0
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): RENDERER: VideoCore IV HW
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): EGLCONFIG: EGLConfig(Red=5, Green=6, Blue=5,   Alpha=0, Depth=0, Stencil=0)
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): EXTENSIONS: GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture  GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_depth24   GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_EGL_image GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_depth32
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS: 8
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 128
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 128
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 8
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onSurfaceCreated @(Thread:    'GLThread 17')
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onReloadResources @(Thread: 'GLThread 17')
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onResumeGame @(Thread: 'GLThread 17')
01-13 20:44:48.867: W/GLThread(16843): onSurfaceChanged(480, 320)
01-13 20:44:48.867: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onSurfaceChanged(Width=480,  Height=320) @(Thread: 'GLThread 17')
01-13 20:44:49.085: E/(16843): RTOS COMMON MEM zero linear buffer allocated 1949696 0 205
01-13 20:44:49.085: E/(16843): BIG MEM OUT OF HANDLES
01-13 20:44:49.132: D/dalvikvm(16843): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 42K, 51% free  3021K/6087K, external 696K/1208K, paused 47ms
01-13 20:44:49.289: E/(16843): Unable to Find Phys Addr for 225a98
01-13 20:44:49.289: E/(16843): RTOS COMMON MEM zero linear buffer allocated 4771840 0 205
01-13 20:44:49.289: E/(16843): BIG MEM OUT OF HANDLES
01-13 20:44:49.539: E/(16843): Unable to Find Phys Addr for 225a98
01-13 20:44:49.593: E/(16843): RTOS COMMON MEM zero linear buffer allocated 360448 0 205
01-13 20:44:49.593: E/(16843): BIG MEM OUT OF HANDLES
01-13 20:44:49.640: E/(16843): Unable to Find Phys Addr for 225a98
01-13 20:44:49.679: D/dalvikvm(16843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 260K, 51% free 3020K/6087K, external 696K/1208K, paused 42ms
01-13 20:44:49.710: E/(16843): Unable to Find Phys Addr for 225a98
01-13 20:44:49.710: E/(16843): Unable to Find Phys Addr for 225a98
01-13 20:44:49.710: E/(16843): Unable to Find Phys Addr for 225a98
01-13 20:44:49.710: E/(16843): Unable to Find Phys Addr for 225a98
01-13 20:44:49.710: E/(16843): Unable to Find Phys Addr for 225a98
01-13 20:44:49.718: E/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglSwapBuffers Error 0x505
01-13 20:44:49.726: W/EglHelper(16843): destroySurface()  tid=17
01-13 20:44:49.726: D/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 16858
01-13 20:44:49.726: D/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x219018, android window 0x2187f8, Thread: 16858
01-13 20:44:49.726: W/EglHelper(16843): finish() tid=17
01-13 20:44:49.726: D/BRCM_EGL(16843): eglDestroyContext() context: 0x266ec8, VC  context: 1, Thread 16858
01-13 20:44:49.734: E/EGL_SERVER(16843): pid mem_get_free_space before =  5ffb80
01-13 20:44:49.734: E/EGL_SERVER(16843): pid mem_get_free_space =  5ffb80
01-13 20:44:49.750: W/dalvikvm(16843): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001c578)
01-13 20:44:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(16843): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 17
01-13 20:44:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(16843): java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS
01-13 20:44:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(16843):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1085)
01-13 20:44:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(16843):    at   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1043)
01-13 20:44:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(16843):    at   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1369)
01-13 20:44:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(16843):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1123)
01-13 20:44:49.835: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onPause @(Thread: 'main')
01-13 20:44:49.835: I/GLThread(16843): onPause tid=17
01-13 20:44:49.835: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onPauseGame @(Thread: 'main')
01-13 20:44:57.968: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onDestroy @(Thread: 'main')
01-13 20:44:57.968: D/AndEngine(16843): UpdateThread interrupted. Don't worry - this EngineDestroyedException is most likely expected!
01-13 20:44:57.968: D/AndEngine(16843): org.andengine.engine.Engine$EngineDestroyedException
01-13 20:44:57.968: D/AndEngine(16843):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.throwOnDestroyed(Engine.java:574)
01-13 20:44:57.968: D/AndEngine(16843):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:560)
01-13 20:44:57.968: D/AndEngine(16843):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
01-13 20:44:57.968: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onDestroyResources @(Thread: 'main')
01-13 20:44:57.968: D/AndEngine(16843): StartActivity.onGameDestroyed @(Thread: 'main')
```

The game works fine on a lot of devices, but crashes with this error on Samsung Galaxy Ace (GT-S5830C). It happens after i close/reopen the game a few times, or switch through game activities a few times.

Actually, this problem does not happens on load/reload of the game if i kill the process on game exit. It also does not happens when switching activities if i don't call GLSurfaceView.onPause() when the activity is paused. Both are not good practices, but gives us some clues about the problem, since both seems to avoid asset reloading which might be the root cause. Am i missing something?

Could it be a device-related problem? What are the side effects of this workarounds?